# iTerm2 + TMUX closing behaviour

Tags: tmux, iterm2

I've just discovered tmux integration with iTerm2 and it's fantastic! The only thing that I'd love to change is the exit behavior on closing the window. The current behavior exit's the tmux session. I would like it to detach instead.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to press `esc` from the tmux command menu? If that works it should cleanly detach the session and next time you can attach to it after opening iTerm.